# Android: How can I get the facing direction of the phone and the angle of view

Tags: android, camera, direction

I want to calculate the overlapped area between two phones, so I need to know the facing direction of the phone and also the angle of view of the camera. Does anybody know how to get these information? Thanks!

Following is an example:

```
\ \  / /
 \ \/ /
  \/\/
```

camera1  camera2

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the compass to acquire that information but not all phones have it... it probably won't be that precise either.

Comment: My phone does have compass, so how to use compass?